# Jquery datatable group by two columns with expand and collapse

Tags: jquery, datatable, grouping

**references**:

1. [Two level grouping](https://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/twoLevelGrouping.html)
2. [One level grouping with expand and collapse](https://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/customization.html)

I want the datatable as in #1, but with the feature of #2 for both the levels, that is both levels can be expanded and collapsed.

**fiddle reference:** *jsfiddle.net/RgKPZ/488/*

If there is any other similar plugin other than jquery datatables, please let me know that as well.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-grouping/wiki/Options):

```
.rowGrouping({
    iGroupingColumnIndex1:2,
    bExpandableGrouping: true, // expand/collapse first column
    bExpandableGrouping2: true // expand/collapse second column
 });
```

updated [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RgKPZ/493/), you can set indentations with css.

Comment: this jsfiddle.net/RgKPZ/493/ is not an example of two column expand/collapse.